# Excel > Find the correct data row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel table with three pages. Page 1 will be a web-ran report, page 2 will be the DB report and page 3 is my comparison.

What I am struggling to do or understand and find online, are examples of grabbing the staff number from let's say A2 on DB, comparing it to A2 on the web, and then grabbing their specific manager.

The scripts I have made for comparison are;

users not found DB to web
`=COUNTIF(C:C, "Not found")`

managers not found from DB to web
`=COUNTIF(J:J, "Incorrect")`

DB to Export Comparison
`=IFNA(VLOOKUP(DB!A2,Report!A:A,1,FALSE),"Not found")`

DB Team Manager check
`=IFNA(VLOOKUP(Report!D2, DB!D:D,1,FALSE),DB!D2)`

Web Team Manager
`=IFNA(VLOOKUP(DB!D2, Report!D:D,1,FALSE),Report!D2)`

Do managers match
`=IF(F2=G2,"Yes","Incorrect")`

How would it be best for the manager cell to grab the 'Staff Number' from the comparison page, locate it on the DB and then grab the manager in the cell next to it... and also in Web?

Thanks very much!

[Comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNviI.png)

[DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nr4TN.png)

[repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejxJb.png)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by playing around and watching the Video on https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1 of VLOOKUP

Comment: Consider adding a more comprehensive answer in case someone with similar issues comes here. Link-only answers are not considered good here